# не могу добавить переменную в базу данных postgresql (psycopg2)

Tags: python, sql, база-данных, postgresql, psycopg2

не могу решить проблему.Мне нужно добавить переменную с логином и паролем пользователя в базу данных,но мне выдает вот такую ошибку:

```
cur.execute("INSERT INTO registr (login) VALUES (%s)"%t)
psycopg2.errors.SyntaxError: ОШИБКА:  ошибка синтаксиса (примерное положение: ".")
LINE 1: INSERT INTO registr (login) VALUES (.!entry)
                                        ^
```

а вот мой код:

```
def jop():
    lbl.configure(text='Вы зарегистрировались',bg='white')
    if not t.get():
        lbl.configure(text='введите логин!')
    elif not p.get():
        lbl.configure(text='введите пароль!')
    cur.execute("INSERT INTO registr (login) VALUES (%s)"%t)
    cur.execute("INSERT INTO registr (password) VALUES (%s)"%p)
    connection.commit()

    


jopa = Tk()  
jopa.title("Регистрация")  
jopa.geometry('400x600')
lbl = Label(jopa, text="Привет",bg='brown1',)  
t=Entry(bg='white')
p=Entry(show='*')
bt=Button(jopa,text='Начать',command=jop,bg='white')
jopa["bg"] = "brown1"



lbl.pack()
t.pack()
p.pack()
bt.pack()



jopa.mainloop()
```

пожалуйста помогите!

Comment: Во первых один insert добавляет одну запись. У вас 2 insert следовательно вы пытаетесь добавить две записи, одну с логином и другую с паролем. Во вторых psycopg2 сам подставляет переменные, не надо пытаться это делать за него. Посмотрите примеры, приведенные в документации, там как раз правильные варианты insert ... https://www.psycopg.org/docs/usage.html#passing-parameters-to-sql-queries

Comment: большое спасибо)))